# MySQL - Select with LIKE and Nulls

Tags: mysql, null, asp-classic, sql-like

I need to inform a list of clients and they agents.

But many clients didn't had an agent. (and the adm will insert the data)

Then my SELECT retuns:

```
=============
CLIENT - AGENT
ABC INC - MARK
DEF INC - MARK
GHI INC - JOHN
YXZ INC - NULL
---------------
```

The ADM have a "Search" engine to select only clients for  some agent.

and my Select is:

```
SELECT 
CLIENTS.ID AS CLIENT, CLIENTS.NAME AS NAME, AGENTS.NAME AS AGENT FROM CLIENTS  
LEFT JOIN AGENTS ON  AGENTS.CLIENTID = CLIENTS.ID  
WHERE CLIENTS.NAME LIKE '%"&CLIENTNAME&"%' AND AGENTS.NAME LIKE '%"&AGENTNAME&"%'"
```

When I use LIKE %% they bring ALL AGENTS. 
When I use LIKE %MARK% they bring ALL AGENTS WITH MARK

but.. with LIKE %% I dont had the "NULL" Agents..

And I need this info too..

any idea to bring the NULL?

I'm working with Classic ASP.

Comment: Just skip that condition `LIKE '%%'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add something like below:

`....WHERE IFNULL(CLIENTS.NAME,'') LIKE '%%'...`

Comment: Hi @1000111 first of all tks for your time and help. Great, elegant and brillant solution! Works perfectly! Save my life! tks a lot!!!!!!

Comment: You are welcome Dear! If I am not wrong once I fell in the same problem. It took much time to figure out why data get missing. Then found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Within parentheses add an additional clause to include NULLs:

```
... AND (AGENTS.NAME LIKE '%"&AGENTNAME&"%' OR AGENTS.NAME IS NULL)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your query like this :

```
SELECT 
CLIENTS.ID AS CLIENT, CLIENTS.NAME AS NAME, AGENTS.NAME AS AGENT FROM CLIENTS  
LEFT JOIN AGENTS ON  AGENTS.CLIENTID = CLIENTS.ID  
WHERE CLIENTS.NAME LIKE '%"&CLIENTNAME&"%' AND (AGENTS.NAME LIKE '%"&AGENTNAME&"%'" OR AGENTS.NAME IS NULL)
```

Comment: hi @md-khairul-hasan tks a lot for your time and help! I Will try this - but - with this query I will receive ALL AGENTS + NULL (is ok for me) - but if I need a list of agents with "MARK" or "JOHN" - i will receive the NULL too?

Comment: hi, yep.. its a problem to me - because the "Null list" had a lot of registers.. If the ADM filter by "MARK" they receive only 2 "MARK" but 20.000 nulls.. :D.. the best solution is what @1000111 post. Anyway, tks a looooooooot to share your knowledge with me too.